# Why isn't this value a valid DateTime object?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, xpath, xml-parsing

I am pretty new in **XPath** and I have the following problem.

I am working on a **C#** class that read an XML file and using the content of its fields sets an object properties.

In this class I have the following instruction:

```
currentDeepSightVuln.Published = n_alertdocument.SelectSingleNode("./x:Published", nsmgr) == null ? DateTime.MinValue : DateTime.Parse(n_alertdocument.SelectSingleNode("./x:Published", nsmgr).InnerText);
```

This instruction set the value of the **Published** property of the **currentDeepSightVuln** object using the following field into an XML file:

```
<x:Published>Mar 11 2014</x:Published>
```

So, using the previous value (**Mar 11 2014**) my program thrown the following exception:

> ex    {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of
>   week was incorrect."} System.Exception {System.FormatException}

But if instead of the **Mar 11 2014** value I use the **Sep 19 2011** (in another XML file that I am using as testing I found Sep 19 2011) I have no exception and my program work fine.

Why the **Mar 11 2014** value is not good as **DateTime** value?

What can I do to solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: What happens if you change `Mar 11 2014` to `Sep 19 2011` do you still get the same error?

Comment: What is the currentthread (UI) culture you're using?

Comment: What happens if you write 2014-03-11 ?

Comment: Andrea,

seems like you put an extra space in Mar 11 2014, in your Published tag of your XML. Can you check again?

Comment: I tried reproducing this, and was unable to get the same error, even trying different cultures (tried Italian, Spanish, UK and US English - all work).  Like @Jesse says, it's likely to be a culture issue, but without knowing your specific culture settings, impossible to be certain

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("MAR 11 2014", "MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is internationalization/localization. Your operating system (and/or .NET Framework) might have additional language packs installed.

For example, in Italian, I believe "Mar" is the abbreviation to "Martedì", which means Tuesday. Similarly, in Spanish "Mar" is also the abbreviation to "Martes", which, again, means Tuesday.

I think what might be happening is that the interpretation of the date/time is unsure of which locale to use, and much less sure of which predefined format to use.

You can include the full month name in the XML string, and see that it will work: "March 11 2014".

However, it seems as if you are working strictly with English-formatted date/times - why not force the parsing method to look for a single/specific format? Similar to what [vvv answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24014380/238722), see below:

```
string pattern = "MMM dd yyyy";
DateTime parsedDate;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1:d}.", dateValue, parsedDate);
}
```